# script is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have one script as following:

**CODE :**

```
<script>    

    var ul = document.getElementById("foo2");
    var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i=i+2) {
      // do something with items[i], which is a <li> element
      items[i].style="border-bottom:5px solid #1d4295;";
    }    

</script>
```

This is working properly in firefox but not in chrome?

Comment: you are not using jquery here.It is javascript.Use some debugging tool in chrome to address the issue.Find errors thrown in javascript console

Comment: Are you sure you have used jQuery , it looks like pure js to me

Comment: Did you mean ${items[i]}.css('border-bottom', '5px solid #1d4295') ?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
items[i].style="border-bottom:5px solid #1d4295;";
```

with

```
items[i].style.borderBottom = "5px solid #1d4295";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNt3C/2/)

or you could just use jQuery

```
$('#foo2 li:even').css('border-bottom', '5px solid #1d4295');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNt3C/3/)